# My question is about reducing camera nervousness

Tags: stage-fright

I am about to shoot for my first music video for a big band but am very nervous . I don't wish to spoil the entire song just because of my nervousness ... how can I destress myself or make myself feel comfortable

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly ensure you know what you're performing inside out. I record and upload piano videos on Instagram and before I press record I play over what I'm going to be recording countless times, so much that I can play it with my eyes shut and without even thinking about it.
2. Secondly, whilst recording don't think about the camera just enjoy yourself and involve yourself in the music. When I play with my big band in front of an audience, I just forget about the audience and really get into the music and have a laugh with the other trumpeters.
3. This might seem a bit odd but it's worth a try... meditate. I have an app called headspace that I use before performing because it just chills me out completely.

I think step 1 is the most important, if you know your music inside out you won't be worrying about slipping up and therefore you're also going to be far more relaxed. Knowing the music 'technically' also helps on the performance side of things as it means you can then just concentrate on putting emotion into the music.